# Angular groupBy filter throwing error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to group my messages using created date. But , if i apply the filter I am getting an error as   **Unknown provider: groupByFilterProvider <- groupByFilter**

I am expecting my results to be grouped by time for example,

1:24 PM

Hi 
Hello

etc..

But, what I am getting klike this without using groupBy filter.
Hi 1: 24 PM
Hello 1:24 PM like that.

I am created a fiddle for this please look into that and suggest me to fix this issue. https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/4/

I have used

```
groupBy: 'created'
```

Comment: I think your fiddle link is wrong, it has nothing to do with the groupBy filter

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/4/

Comment: what am I missing, I see "Hello Foo", an input text field and a login button. the code does not contain any groupBy filter

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience , I have updated the right link https://jsfiddle.net/karthe03/Lt7aP/3273/

Answer (score 0):

groupBy does not come out of the box with AngularJS, you need https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby

here's the code, however you will have to truncate the `created` member of the array because the `groupBy` will see them as different values. I have done so at the end of the controller

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter','a8m.group-by']);

myApp.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.map = {
    "Today": [{
      "msg": "jhyhj",
      "userId": "800",
      "profileImagePath": "",
      "created": 1472541041844,
      "from": "Dev"
    }, {
      "msg": "jghjg",
      "userId": "800",
      "profileImagePath": "",
      "created": 1472541043213,
      "from": "Dev"
    }, {
      "msg": "hii",
      "userId": "800",
      "profileImagePath": "",
      "created": 1472543443842,
      "from": "Dev"
    }, {
      "msg": "hii",
      "userId": "800",
      "profileImagePath": "",
      "created": 1472543481505,
      "from": "Dev"
    }, {
      "msg": "hello",
      "userId": "800",
      "profileImagePath": "",
      "created": 1472548350369,
      "from": "Dev"
    }, {
      "msg": "hello",
      "userId": "800",
      "profileImagePath": "",
      "created": 1472548351702,
      "from": "Dev"
    }, {
      "msg": "hello",
      "userId": "800",
      "profileImagePath": "",
      "created": 1472548353023,
      "from": "Dev"
    }]
  };
  angular.forEach($scope.map["Today"],function(val,idx){
    val.created = $filter('date')(val.created, 'shortTime')
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.11/angular-filter.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="LoginController">
  <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in map">
    <p>
      {{key}}
    </p>
    <div ng-repeat="(created,msgs) in value | groupBy : 'created'">
      <b>{{created | date : 'shortTime'}}</b>
      <p ng-repeat="msg in msgs">{{msg.msg}} </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```